# I don't understand how the remainders were calculated in relation to this question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm solving a question which requires me to find a number 'n' such that n-9, n-3, n+3, n+9 are consecutive prime numbers and n, n-8, n-4, n+4, n+8 are practical numbers and then I have to add the first four 'n' that satisfy this condition. This is a computation problem which is goes up to really really large numbers

The solution i came up with is bad but others have given different solutions that are better, and they all have the same part:

```
n % 2 = 0
n % 3 = 2
n % 4 = 0
n % 5 = 0
n % 7 = 6
n % 8 = 4
```

but i don't understand how these were calculated? One of the comments explaining it for n % 7 is as follows:

```
Because n-9, n-3, n+3 and n+9 are prime, n must be expressed as 7*m7 or 7*m7+1 or 7*m7+6 (4)
One of n-8, n, n+8 is divisible by 7, and n-4 and n+4 are never.
```

and for n % 5:

```
Because n-9, n-3, n+3 and n+9 are prime, n must be divisible by 5: n=5*m5 (3)
n-8, n-4, n+4, n+8 are not divisible by 5.
```

and n % 3:

```
 n-3 is prime, so n is not divisible by 3. Suppose that n=3*m3+1 (1)
 n-4 and n+8 are divisible by 3 and n-8, n and n+4 are not.
```

but i still don't understand any of these. Could someone please explain? And why stop at n % 8 and not continue to n % 9 or n % 11 for that matter? I can't ask the original authors btw, it's been like 12 years

Comment: What is a practical number?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos wiki explains it the best imo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos practical number is a positive integer n such that all smaller positive integers can be represented as sums of distinct divisors of n. For example, 12 is a practical number because all the numbers from 1 to 11 can be expressed as sums of its divisors 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6: as well as these divisors themselves, we have 5 = 3 + 2, 7 = 6 + 1, 8 = 6 + 2, 9 = 6 + 3, 10 = 6 + 3 + 1, and 11 = 6 + 3 + 2.

Comment: the numbers remainders modulo 7 going down by 1 each entry show that one end would have to be 7 if the remainder on the first is 3, or the last is 4 ...   likewise we note that  residues mod an odd number  are only prime with an opposite parity multiplier.  so there needs be a multiple of 7  in between each pair.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I'm sorry but I'm still having a bit of difficulty understanding what you just said. What is an opposite parity multiplier and what do you mean by going down 1 each entry?

Comment: odd times odd is odd, and adding a remainder to get an odd number ( since all primes other than 2 are odd)  forces even remainders at most to work.  however odd times even is even, therefore forcing odd remainders at most to work. $6\equiv -1\pmod 7$